# Constant time removing element in an stl container

Tags: c++, stl

Simple question : Is there any STL container that allows me to delete the current iterator position in constant time ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `std::list` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase

Comment: note: still, if you support other operations, consider (measure) `vector`. double linked lists have a lot of overhead

Comment: It's worth noting that any non-sorted container can swap an element at any position with an element at the end (or the beginning) of the container and then delete the last/first element. This allows deletion in constant time provided swapping the value_type of the container in question can be done in constant time. This technique has been explained in [this talk](https://youtu.be/oBbGC-sUYVA?t=155) at CppCon 2016

Comment: Any of the node-based containers should have constant-time removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) has [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) with complexity:

> Complexity
>
> 1) Constant.
>
> 2) Linear in the distance between first and last.

where for case 2 you use erase for a range of elements.

from the docs, `std::list<T>::erase` looks like this:

```
//(1)
iterator erase( iterator pos );
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
//(2)   
iterator erase( iterator first, iterator last );
iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
```

another one is [std::forward_list](http://std::forward_list) (not exactly the same because it only has `erase_after`)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to maintain the order of the elements you can use `std::vector` with "swap and pop" - you swap the element you want to delete with the last element in the vector, and then pop the new last element.

Comment: is this as fast as removing an element form a linked list?

Comment: @AryanParekh they're both O(1) and I assume vector will be faster since it's more cache friendly. You could benchmark it to see if that's the case for you.

Comment: But let's say I wanna swap `vec[vec.size-1]` and `x`. Still gotta find x right?

Comment: @AryanParekh if you have to find it first that's a different problem. The question states there's already an iterator available so no need for search.

Answer (score 2):

At least std::list allow to erase element in constant time.